# Delete product from database(don't display in listview) using button placed in listview

Tags: android

My problem is in title(I've been looking for an answer on stackoverflow, but no solution in my case). I've been trying to do it using `setOnItemClickListener`, but clicking on row in `ListView` does nothing. Also I've tried using `myClick()` - which is action when button is clicked, but here I don't know how to connect clicked button with row in database.

My activity with layout:
http://pastebin.com/6KLBm80Q

Database class + adapter + layout of listview row
http://pastebin.com/G2HufNgS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must override `getView()` in your `Adapter` and set `setOnClickListener()` (and/or `setOnLongClickListener()`) for an item within your list item. That item will receive the clicks.

Comment: He should also override getItemId() in the Adapter

Comment: Ok, I will try doing both.

Comment: Any help, example how to do it? Should I just move my setOnClickListener() from my activity to Adapter or what?

Comment: Sorry to waste your time, but I started down the path of overriding 'getView()' so I could set a 'setOnClickListener()' in there and I found that my existing code from other projects is not using my advice. I am using a single 'setOnItemClickListener()' same as your original question. Therefore, I cancel my advice above (and I will soon delete this answer). Something else is disallowing your click function from getting called. Can you confirm that neither of your Toast messages are being displayed ('onItemClickListener()' and 'myClick()')?? I will look into it further soon.

Comment: myClick() toast is working, while I am clicking button in listview. One from onItemClickListener() is not working.